# How to add custom values in ion-checkbox?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, checkbox, ngmodel

I want to know an optimal way of setting the custom values for ion-checkbox.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsi4d.png)

i have tried this but it is not working.

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item-group lines="inset" *ngFor="let section of item.value">
      <ion-item-divider class="bg-light">
        <ion-label>{{section.sectionName}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item-divider>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let menu of section.menuItems">
        <ion-label
          ><strong *ngIf="menu.quantity">({{menu.quantity}})</strong>
          {{menu.name}}
          <strong>+ $ {{menu.price | number:'1.2-2'}}</strong></ion-label
        >
        <ion-checkbox
          slot="end"
          (ionChange)="checkBoxChange($event, menu.menuItemId, menu.name)"
          [(ngModel)]="menu.checked"
        ></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item-group>
  </ion-list>
```